# Returning image data via express route

Tags: html, node.js, image, express, blob

I need to return **image data** to an html element that is linked to an **express route**.

My html **`<img>`** tag looks like this

```
<img class="image" crossorigin="anonymous" src="/a/OIkhg2P2QoOV3qiOByvwxQ/xyz.png">
```

My express route looks like this: Here the **img_url** is a url to the image on a different site.

```
router.get('/a/:projectLocator/:fileName', function (req, res) {    
    const img_url = base64_decode(req.params.projectLocator) + req.params.fileName;
    request.get(img_url, (error, response, body) => {
        res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
        res.send(body);
});
```

This code does not seem to work as the image does not render on the client. The server returns without any error.

Am I doing something wrong here ? I am setting the mime type correctly.

Any help would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` has a streaming interface. Try to use that. It will be better on speed and memory.

```
router.get('/a/:projectLocator/:fileName', function (req, res) {    
    const img_url = base64_decode(req.params.projectLocator) + req.params.fileName;
    res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
    request.get(img_url).pipe(res)
});
```

example: https://repl.it/@ktilcu/images